# Como lidar com perguntas que misturam especificidades de programação e de linguística?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Achei interessante a pergunta [How to distinguish Brazilian Portuguese from European Portuguese](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3700/how-to-distinguish-brazilian-portuguese-from-european-portuguese) porque ela nem é sobre programação nem é sobre língua portuguesa, ou antes é sobre as duas.

Á primeira vista, deveria ser considerada inválida mas eu não acho que esta seja a melhor abordagem porque ela também não pode ser respondida dentro de um âmbito meramente técnico.

No caso em questão, pode-se olhar aspectos gramaticas como o uso do *fa**C**to* ou do *fato*, do *usuário* ou do *utilizador* mas há também outros pontos mais específicos como a formatação da data *26/09/2016* ou *29-09-2016*, da moeda *R$* ou *€*, do language code *pt_BR* ou *pt_PT* e de outras características ainda mais específicas.

Nada disso se encaixa nem aqui no *Portuguese Language* nem num fórum de programação e a pergunta provavelmente não será respondida nem num lado nem no outro.

No âmbito do StackExchange há pelo menos uma área sobre desenvolvimento, o  [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Na minha opinião, o correto procedimento para perguntas desse tipo seria adicionar uma tag específica - eu sugeriria [computational-linguistics](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computational-linguistics) - e obrigar a criação da pergunta no [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) com a respectiva resposta lá.

Isso porque seria estranho colocar aqui respostas com código e pseudo-código no *Portuguese Language* e assim, de futuro quem tivesse a mesma dúvida poderia encontrar a o link para resposta correta aqui mesmo que ela tenha sido respondida lá.

Assim sendo, tem sentido considerar como inválidas perguntas como "*How to distinguish Brazilian Portuguese from European Portuguese*" ou é melhor adotar uma abordagem tão mista quanto a pergunta e obrigar/permitir crosslinking entre o *Portuguese Language* e o *StackOverflow*?

Comment: Eduardo, o problema é que ela também não é boa para o StackOverflow, se fosse eu tinha migrado a pergunta. A pergunta é muito ampla aqui, ou em qualquer dos outros sites. Se ele quiser saber uma coisas especifica como datas **OU** moeda, etc então a pergunta já se poderia encaixar até aqui, com um bocado de jeito. Assim como está é ampla em qualquer lado.

Comment: Daí a sugestão. Focando a pergunta num site de desenvolvimento e colocando aberta aqui com a ênfase só na linguística, resolvia. Eu fico pensando que esta é uma pergunta que eu mesmo faria em algumas ocasiões, com línguas diferentes.

Comment: Olha, a pergunta não é técnica. Se ele estivesse perguntando, sei lá, sobre se é melhor usar C++ ou Pascal para resolver esse tipo de problema, seria uma pergunta técnica. Mas eu suponho que ele sabe resolver esse aspecto da questão. O que ele não sabe é português. E aí, claro, é uma pergunta sobre língua portuguesa.

Comment: Também não vejo como a pergunta seja ampla demais. Se fosse uma pergunta sobre "as diferenças" entre português do Brasil e de Portugal, seria talvez ampla demais. Mas não é: é uma pergunta bem específica: quais características, num texto escrito, um computador poderia usar para diferenciar PT/PT de PT/BR. Ninguém precisa saber computação para responder isso, e não é uma pergunta enciclopédica. Basta apontar para fatos tais como "ct" e "cç" são mais raros no PT/BR do que no PT/PT, "óm" só se econtra no PT/PT, "peúga" não pode ser encontrado em PT/BR, etc.

Comment: @LuísHenrique pensa bem em todos os casos que existem e, mesmo ideintificando padrões, vê lá se não seria uma resposta grande demais?

Comment: Não acho, @JorgeB. A resposta eu dei num comentário na pergunta: procurar por "óm" e "ón" *versus* "ôm" e "ôn". Claro, existe o risco de um texto não conter proparoxítonas com "o" tônico ("tónico") seguido de consoante nasal. Então se eu fosse montar um algorítmo, eu o basearia nessa particularidade.

Comment: @LuísHenrique E as outras particularidades todas não importam?

Comment: Não, a menos que estejamos diante de um texto do qual não constem proparoxítonas com "o" seguido de consoante nasal. Um texto que tem "óm" ou "ón" é um texto em PT/PT. Um texto que tem "ôm" e "ôn" é um texto em PT/BR. Não conheço nenhuma outra particularidade que seja tão geral, nem mesmo "ém" e "én", porquanto existem as palavras "também", "porém" e "parabéns" em PT/BR

Comment: @LuísHenrique até poderia ser, mas e se não tiver "óm"? O autor não referiu nada especifico. Ou achas que essa regra serve para todos os textos? Viste o comentário do @tchrist?